# Javascript Hide/Show Button Does Not Work Properly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to add Javascript show/hide button to show and hide a dive element of my page.

This is my code:

```
while($r = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
    echo "
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>What is the equivalent?</title>
            <style>
            .center{
                margin-left:50%;
            }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class='center'>
                <div class='show'>
                    <form action='' method='POST'>
                        <h1>".$r->german."</h1>
                        <h5>".$r->table_id."</h5>
                        <p><input type='submit' value='Show' onclick='myFunction()'></input></p></br>
                        <div id='myDIV'>
                            This is my DIV element.
                        </div>
                        <p></p>
                    </form>
                    <a href='en-de.php' style='text-decoration:none'>En to De</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <p>$count</p>
        </body>
        <script>
        function myFunction() {
          var x = document.getElementById('myDIV');
          if (x.style.display === 'none') {
            x.style.display = 'block';
          } else {
            x.style.display = 'none';
          }
        }
        </script>
    </html>
    ";
}
```

As you can see I have set this `<input type='submit' value='Show' onclick='myFunction()'></input>` and the `myFunction()` is called at the bottom between script tags.

But the problem is it does not work out and div within id of `myDIV` is always shown at the page.

So how to fix this? What's going wrong here?

Comment: Because your `input` is of type `submit`, the page will reload, undoing any changes that have been made through Javascript.

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and create a [mcve] WITHOUT PHP - this is not a PHP issue at all. Just paste JS, HTML and relevant CSS. Change the button to type="button" or access the submit event and use `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: You are currently echoing an entire HTML document on a while loop. Also, IDs in HTML must be unique, meaning you cannot have multiple divs of ID `myDIV` (well you can, but this will be error-prone)

Comment: @AnisR. You can have multiple elements with the same `id`. You just need to be careful about what you do.

Comment: @Rojo If you need to NOT use the ID because it is duplicate, don't have the ID at all

Comment: @Rojo Right, but this is error-prone, since `getElementById` will not work as expected. Should have clarified

Comment: Relevant for unique IDs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9454716/2181514  - the spec says it **must be unique** - but browsers know we're a bit useless so don't enforce it, so, yes, you "can" have the same id, but you shouldn't.

Comment: Put an `alert("x")` at the end your for `myFunction` - you'll see the div is not there for the alert, then is back after you close the alert.  Also watch the browser network tab (F12).  Also add a `$(function() { console.log("start") })` (once, in a script tag, outside your `while`) and turn off clear console on refresh to see it appear when you're not expecting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your input type to button

```
<input type='button' value='Show' onclick='myFunction()'></input>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. If you need more than one form, you should delegate
2. Do not loop a complete HTML page
3. Your myDIV is a duplicate ID, use a class instead

Perhaps you meant this - no need for the form at all. If you need a form, use the submit event instead

```js
document.querySelector(".center").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("toggle")) {
    tgt.closest(".show").querySelector(".myDIV").classList.toggle("hide")
  }
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class='center'>
  <div class='show'>
    <h1>german</h1>
    <h5>table_id 1</h5>
    <p><input type='button' value='Show' class="toggle" /></p>
    <div class='myDIV hide'>
      This is my DIV element 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='show'>
    <h1>german</h1>
    <h5>table_id 2</h5>
    <p><input type='button' value='Show' class="toggle" /></p>
    <div class='myDIV hide'>
      This is my DIV element 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<p>$count</p>
```